# apply zoom on sequence image animation and imageview subview of scroll view ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an app which displays a sequence of images.

I want to apply zoom in and zoom out on current image.

The zoom in will be done by pinch effect and zoom out will be done by button click.

What do I have to do?

Comment: Please give more information about your view hierarchy. are you using scrollviews as well? Is the scrollview how you achieve zooming?

Comment: yes view>scrollview>imageView

Comment: And what methods are you using for zooming? How does it operate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You have to set the view which you want to zoom in `UIScrollView`. In your case it must be `UIImageView`

use the method of `UIScrollView`

```
- (UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView: (UIScrollView *) scrollView
{
    return _imageView;
}
```

then you can call the delegate method of `UIScrollView`

```
- (void) scrollViewDidZoom: (UIScrollView *) scrollView
{
    // add ur code here to center ur image position after zooming
}
```

also set properties of `UIScrollView`

```
minimumZoomScale = 1.0
maximumZoomScale = // ACCORDING TO YOU
```

And if you want to Zoom Out on button click, then set `zoomScale = 1.0` of `UIScrollView` on `IBAction` of button

Comment: i am using same code but when i clicked on zoom out button its subview image view going proper position but in scroll view its still in zoom in position

Comment: I have editted my soln. Did you copy paste my minimumZoomScale = 1.0 lines??

Comment: i got it by simple access all scrollview from rootview and apply zomm scale to all i faced this because my view overlapping scrollviews in each and every sequence image. thanks.....:)

Comment: can u please vote up my answer..:)